# Empty folder in HDFS using Spark Streaming+Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am using Spark Streaming + Kafka for data ingestion into HDFS.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(30))
val messageRecBased = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topic)
  .map(_._2)
```

Each 30 sec all data in Kafka queue will be stored in a separate folder in HDFS. Some folders contains a empty file called part-00000 because there is no data in the corresponding batch-interval (30 sec).
I used the following lines to filter those folders:

```
messageRecBased.filter { x => x.size == 0 }
messageRecBased.repartition(1).saveAsTextFiles("PATH")
```

but it is not working and it still generates folders with empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [DStream.saveAsTextFiles()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala) method definition, it simply spawns the `RDD.saveAsObjectFile` to each of the `RDD` in the `DirectKafkaInputDStream`.

```
  def saveAsObjectFiles(prefix: String, suffix: String = ""): Unit = ssc.withScope {
    val saveFunc = (rdd: RDD[T], time: Time) => {
      val file = rddToFileName(prefix, suffix, time)
      rdd.saveAsObjectFile(file)
    }
    this.foreachRDD(saveFunc)
  }
```

So instead of using `DStream.saveAsTextFiles()`, you can chose to write something of your own like:

```
messageRecBased.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
    rdd.repartition(1)
    if(!rdd.isEmpty)
        rdd.saveAsObjectFile("FILE_PATH")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It solves the problem of creating folders with empty file. Now I have one folder with three files: part-00000, part-00001, part00002. Surprisingly messages will be over-write in these three file! So I do not have a file with all messages, I have three file with last three messages! Do you know why?

Comment: I have just one topic.

Comment: def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
           System.exit(1)
    }
    val topic = Map(args(0) -> 1)
    val zkQuorum = args(1)
    val group = "ZZZ"
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext("local[2]", "XXX")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(30))
    val messageRecBased = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topic)
      .map(_._2)
    messageRecBased.foreachRDD{rdd =>
      //rdd.repartition(1)
      if(!rdd.isEmpty())
        rdd.saveAsTextFile("PATH")
    }

Comment: You have commented repartitioning. I guess you have three internal Kafka partitions in your topic, and thus you are having three part files. If you uncomment RDD.repartitioning(1), then you will get one part file.

Comment: Topic:test/PartitionCount:1/ReplicationFactor:1/Configs:
Topic: test     Partition: 0    Leader: 113     Replicas: 113   Isr: 113

Comment: uncomment rdd.repartition(1), the same result. above is topic configuration. Here how I receive data:spark-submit --master yarn --class com.DataIngestion XXX.jar test "KAFKA-BROCKER". I have the same problem. different files which the data will be over-written!

Comment: @RedNay8080, let me try out the code on my machine, and look into the issue.

Comment: My observation is: 1-Dstream.reparation(1) consolidate all files in a batch interval but rdd.repartition(1) cant do that. 2-when we are using Dstream.foreachRDD{rdd=>rdd.saveAs("")} it going to over-write files which are created in a batch interval (30 sec in the example)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the partition is empty and if not then only save the RDD, like this. This code should prevent empty RDDs from saving up.

```
messageRecBased.partitions.isEmpty
```

Comment: you mean messageRecBased.foreachRDD(x =>  if(!x.partitions.isEmpty) {x.saveAsTextFile(msgFileText)} ) ? because "partitions" is not available for Dstream[String]

Comment: @Sunil; There is no partitions() method in DStream.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did to create new directory and avoid empty batches.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime

   messageRecBased.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
        rdd.repartition(1)
        val eachRdd = rdd.map(record => record.value)
        if(!eachRdd.isEmpty)
          eachRdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs/location/"+DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(LocalDateTime.now)+"/")
      }
```